# Why are my handles and anchor point missing in AI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, selections

I'm quite new to using illustrator. My problem is: I'm missing the anchor point.

Usually when you use the direct selection tool and click an object, it should show the anchor points and handles. I don't know why, suddenly today it won't show up.

Answer (score 31):

You might have set 'Hide edges' by mistake.

Try `ctrl-H` (or `cmd-H` on a Mac), which toggles 'Hide edges' on and off.

Or, you can control whether it's set to Hide Edges or Show Edges directly using the option listed in the `View` menu.

---

(it's similar to Hide Extras in Photoshop, which has the same keyboard shortcut)

Comment: In every other mac application Cmd-H hides the app window - I hit this combo all the time subconsciously.

Comment: damn. Too obvious, yet even experienced, I had to come out looking for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

If your handles are also missing, go to View and check if "Show Bounding Box" is active. (Crtl + Shift + B to toggle).