# I cannot see the bounding box in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, selections, bounding-box

I am quite inexperienced in using adobe illustrator.

Usually, when I select something it shows a bounding box around it but for some reason, it doesn't have it.

I already tried **Ctrl + H** to show the bounding box, but that didn't work.
[image]
[Here the file](https://nofile.io/f/qwRn9oE7fX0)

([I have already gone through this post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17020/why-are-my-handles-and-anchor-point-missing-in-ai)).

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the same issue as you, have you tried restarting Ai and/or copy paste everything to a new doc?

Comment: Should i upload the original ai file?

Comment: Let's take this discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot).

Comment: Your question is still unclear: You write "usually..." So, is this happening only in one file or only on one item? And do you get normal behaviour on all other files in your illustrator? Because your file is so trivial, if it were broken, you could re-create it quickly, rather than spending time here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is for *Hide Edges*

What you want is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or **View → Show Bounding Box**.

---

Note that in order to see the Bounding Box you need to be using the *Selection Tool* (<kbd>V</kbd>).

You can also hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while *most* other tools are active to quickly switch to the *Selection Tool*.

---

In your case, it seems that all your paths are in a clipping mask - you can release it via **Right Click → Release Clipping Mask** or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>.

Comment: I used the Ctrl+Shift+B but it did not work.

Comment: It shows around triangle but it does show around circle.

Comment: The bounding box appears around all 3 objects after it is turned on again.

Answer (score 1):

May have something to do with the GPU preview. Try turning that off via Preferences, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> → GPU Performance. Or to switch to CPU Preview, choose View → Preview on CPU.